# Show customers (res.partner) in custom model in odoo

Tags: odoo

I want to show CUSTOMER menu under a custom model, that I created, in a same way as it is being shown in CRM MODULE. In CRM module, it fetches data from 'res.partner' and applies a default filter (customers) on its view.
Can you suggest a way to achieve the same in my custom model?

Answer (score 1):

```
<menuitem id="menu_custom_partner_customer"
          parent="custom_module.parent_menu_id" 
          action="base.action_partner_customer_form"/>
```

Try this code. Otherwise you can write your own action item for `res.partner` and you can call that action from your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following code. I have already tested it. So, It is better for you.

```
<menuitem id="menu_customer_new" name="Customer" parent="your_module_name.your_menu_item_id" action="base.action_partner_customer_form"/>
```

Parent : It will display Customer menu inside given menu.

I am sure this will work for you.

Thanks